# How to measure voltage drop across a wire?

Tags: voltage

I need to measure the voltage drop across a short piece of wire (about .25 to .30 inches long). The wire (a fusible link) is permanently attached to a battery which is permanently connected to a system. There is no way to insert an ammeter. No, measuring the voltage of the battery will not satisfy my problem because each battery is one of many in parallel. Would an electrometer (Keithley or whatever) be a useful device to measure the voltage drop across the short piece of wire? I haven't used and electrometer for decades!

Comment: Just measure it.

Comment: Why are you concerned about inserting an ammeter (used to measure current) when what you want to measure is voltage?

Comment: @DKNguyen because that would only give one parameter, E, and that is meaningless without I.  E=IR.

Comment: You need a sensitive voltmeter for values smaller than one volt. An electrometer may be used as a very sensitive current meter but you need a voltmeter. Just calculate voltage drop from current and resistance before to decide the voltage range to be used.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Oh, I see. The OP wants to measure a voltage drop at some current flow.

Comment: Upon further research, it looks like a nanovoltmeter might do what I want. Something like a Keithley 180 or 181. Anyone hereplay with one of those?

Comment: A nanovoltmeter may much too sensitive, thermovoltages will be a problem. A millivoltmeter will do.

Comment: Ok, a millivolt meter. It's just that I'm probably dealing with a range of 5uv to 3mv. That's a swag. Won't know for sure until I start measuring.

Comment: I found an HP 3478A in hidden in the lab. It has 5 1/2 digits and can resolve to 100nv. Should do what I need. Thanks for all of the info.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would run a constant current from an external power supply and measure the voltage drop on the wire. If my current is 1A, the voltage indicates the exact resistance of the wire, so 4.6mV, for example, would mean 4.6mΩ.
If you can't measure below 0.1mV (100μV), you can increase the current to 10A (if your supply is capable) and that way measure a 10 times smaller resistance.  In this case, 4.6mV would indicate a 0.46mΩ resistance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many low cost Digital Multimeters available that could do the job.  An example is the Aneng 8008 which has a DC voltage resolution of 1 microvolt and costs less than $20.